# What about Azure Cloud Services in the new "Resource Manager world"

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager

I just read a small post of @pierreroman with the title [Azure Cloud Service VS Azure Resource Manager](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/09/17/azure-cloud-service-vs-azure-resource-manager.aspx). Unfortunately I was not able to comment his post (There was an error saving your comment. (Cannot create comment - access denied.)). Therefore and because I think this topic is interesting for many folks who are using azure cloud services right now, I write my "comment" here and send him a tweet. Maybe he or someone else can answer my questions.

I think that more interesting than the "what is the difference between cloud services and resource groups" is the question "should we plan to move from cloud services to azure resource groups?". Is it even possible? Or are we comparing apples to oranges?

What about scaling (for example adding new instances of a worker role with a simple slider or with auto scaling)?

Comment: I just looked at that article. It contains a number of inaccuracies. The question "should we plan to move from cloud services to azure resource groups" isn't really an answerable question (at least objectively) - and in your case, it appears you're using Cloud Service in the context of web/worker roles (which is different than cloud services containing VMs).

Comment: Hey David. Thank you. Yes, that's what I thought. And yes, we are using web/worker roles. Therefore cloud services (web/worker roles) are a different thing living next to ARM?

Comment: Virtual Machine Scale Sets is an ARM backed resource that can give similar functionality as Cloud Services. If you can do with less control over the instances (vms) App Services is another great option.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is kind of apples(Cloud Service) and grocery(ARM) where can manage fruits, meats, and fishes.

But, very first concept of Cloud Service was similar to the ARM. That's why sometimes confusing.

Below quote is from free ebook [Azure Web Apps for Developers (download)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/B/C/CBCAE9DD-04B7-4585-81FE-8A8E4CC46477/Microsoft_Press_eBook_Azure_Web_Apps_for_Developers_PDF.pdf), page 12 and 13.

> An Azure Resource Group is a logical container for grouping Azure resources.
>
> Grouping resources this way helps simplify the implementation, deployment, management, and monitoring of resources in the resource group. From a billing perspective, it gives you a way to view costs for the resource group rather than for individual resources, eliminating the need to figure out which resources are related. You can think of an Azure Resource Group as a unit of management.

The last line helps to understand clearly, Azure Resource Group is a *unit of management*.